How to evaluate elements of a character vector inside a function in R to dynamically create data variables?
I have a dataset similar to this:
library(tibble)
df <- data.frame(
  basket = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8"),
  fruits = c("orange, apple", "apple", "pineapple, banana", "strawberry, apple, watermelon", "blueberry, pear", "apple, papaya", "apple", "strawberry")
)
print(df)

  basket                        fruits
1     A1                 orange, apple
2     A2                         apple
3     A3             pineapple, banana
4     A4 strawberry, apple, watermelon
5     A5               blueberry, pear
6     A6                 apple, papaya
7     A7                         apple
8     A8                    strawberry

Var basket indicates the basket name, and var fruits describes the different types of fruit each basket contains.
I would like to create a series of dummy variables that indicate whether a basket contains a particular fruit. The final data should look like this:
  basket                      fruits apple strawberry papaya
1     A1                orange,apple     1          0      0
2     A2                       apple     1          0      0
3     A3            pineapple,banana     0          0      0
4     A4 strawberry,apple,watermelon     0          1      0
5     A5              blueberry,pear     0          0      0
6     A6                apple,papaya     1          0      1
7     A7                       apple     1          0      0
8     A8                  strawberry     0          1      0

The dataset is much larger and more complex than this (many more baskets and many more types of fruit). I am only interested in a couple different fruits here: apple, strawberry, and pineapple.
So far, I have tried to go about this by creating a character vector of the fruits I'm interested in and calling elements of that vector into a function that iteratively creates the dummy variables of interest with dplyr's mutate, if_else and a couple stringr functions that detect whether the fruit is present at the start, middle, or end of the fruits variable:
fruits_list <- c("apple", "strawberry", "papaya")

create_ind_vars <- function(df, num) {
  df %>% 
    mutate("ind_{{num}}" := if_else(
      charges == !! rlang::sym(paste0(num))
      | str_starts(charges, !! rlang::sym(paste0(num, ",")))
      | str_detect(charges, !! rlang::sym(paste0(",", num, ",")))
      | str_ends(charges, !! rlang::sym(paste0(",", num))),
      1, 0
    ))
}

testdat <- create_ind_vars(df, fruits_list)

I tried replicating code from this post which explains how to dynamically assign column names on the left side of the := operator, and this post which explains how to dynamically evaluate arguments on the right hand side of the := operator. However, I come across the following error:
Error in `rlang::sym()`:
! Can't convert a character vector to a symbol.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I expect this may be because I'm asking it to input values from a character vector rather than directly in the function line, but am unsure of how to address that.
I am new to user-created functions in R and am unsure if this is a sensible approach. Evaluating an element of the character vector as an argument inside the function seems like the most intuitive approach to me but I could be wrong. I have been reading as many forums as I can find on iterative variable creation in R but have thus far not found one which explains how to evaluate an element of a character vector both on the left and right sides of the := operator inside mutate to create variables.
Thanks for the help!

splitstackshape::cSplit_e(df, "fruits", sep = ", ", type = "character", fill = 0) generates dummy variables for all the fruits. You can then just select the ones that you are interested in.
